# About the steps in a book about Quantum Field Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, field-theory, vacuum

I have a question about the steps in the book "An Introduction To Quantum Field Theory" By Peskin & Schroeder.
In page 213, i don't understand why the $e^{iPx}$ before the $<\Omega|$ in equation 7.4 disappear in the second line.
Please help me^^.

[image]

Comment: Simply, the vacuum is translation invariant

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does $\langle\Omega|\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}Px}=\langle\Omega|\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}0x}$? $(\langle\Omega| =$ ground state of the interacting theory)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/99920/)

Comment: Thank you i understand now@@